# Iterate data from other model records inside custom module in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, erp

I want to iterate account.invoice in my custom module. I am using following line for the iteration but it is not working properly.

> for filex in
>   self.env['account.invoice'].search_read([],['partner_id','status','date_due']):

Comment: What is the result it gives you and what you would like to obtain instead?

Comment: unable to iterate on bool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*search_read* returns a dict ([check this](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.org/en/latest/environment.html#search-read)), thus you need to iterate like this:

```
for (key, value) in self.env['account.invoice'].search_read([],['partner_id','status','date_due']).iteritems():
```